# Photoshop hair selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This hair should be easy to extract, because of strong contrast, but from some reason it's not for me.
Here is the original

[image: original]

Here is my result using quick selection tool
[image: using quick selection]

And here my best using Refine Edge feature
[image]

Any help ?
I'm using Photoshop cs5 extended.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD. These post might answer your question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7945/select-background-against-trees-hair 

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/how-to-decontaminate-black-edges-on-hair

Comment: @boblet, thanks, I will try. But, what is then the purpose of Refine Edge feature? It is so glorified on the web.

Comment: Refine Edge is great for many things, unfortunately with delicate, intricate shapes any automated process is almost always lacking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Techniques for cutting out hair accurately](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/techniques-for-cutting-out-hair-accurately)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decontaminate black edges on hair](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/how-to-decontaminate-black-edges-on-hair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Boblet. Making a channel and converting it into a selection is the way to go. I also use the brush and smudge tools to clean-up and enhance my selection to cutting it to make the hair look more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

The magic wand tool is a fickle beast. You can play with the tolerance levels, but I would recommend just using a polygonal lasso to extract the hair, copying it to a new layer, and gently tending the edges with eraser/feather. Then, fill in the layer behind this new one with black as appropriate and you'll have a nice clean version.

[image]

**(very hastily done, but you get the idea)*

**Side-by-side comparison**

[image]

Comment: kcdwane, could you do the same using white as new background? It seems you just copied my original image.

Comment: You really can't tell the difference? I could, but it would require cutting out the entire subject, smoothing, and changing the background... Look closely at the hair..