# How to blend in a portrait with lots of loose hair on a dark background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal

I have an image of a child I isolated. When I choose a dark or non-bright background for her picture, her hair is not looking good: a halo of white remains around it.

[image]

on white background:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: @ryan : may a simple question for experts

Comment: I copyedited and clarified your question somewhat. If I changed anything beyond your original meaning, feel free to [edit] it back!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Techniques for cutting out hair accurately](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/techniques-for-cutting-out-hair-accurately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a copy of your 'cut out' layer and set the blending mode of that copy layer to DARKEN rather than NORMAL (sometimes MULTIPLY, COLOUR BURN or a different blending mode will work better than darken, depends on the background). This should sit behind the original cut out which should still be set to NORMAL.

You then need to mask the two layers so that the DARKEN layer is only used for the wispy bits of hair and the layer that is set to NORMAL does everything else. You could just erase the wispy bits from the NORMAL layer, but I would recommend using layer masks as it is reversible / non destructive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i just used the color burn and got perfect results. thanks indeed.

Comment: i guess the color burn is better than those two blending modes.  and suggest you to put it in your answer for guiding others.

Comment: Added. It's unusual for colour burn to be the best option though, for most situations multiply or darken will be the best choice because colour burn can look harsh and unnatural. Subjective I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Here are four methods which I use when using photoshop.

1. Defringe

Layer > Matting > Defringe

Set the pixel to 1 to start, you may need to increase this.

2. Feather

Select > modify > contract

try to contract the selection by 1 or 2 pixels to begin with

3. Eraser tool

use a very soft brush for the eraser tool and lower the opacity. Lightly brush the edges of the image with the brush, this will lower the opacity of the white pixels and the edges will start to blend.

4. Refine Edges

Select > refine edge

Play around with this will tool to find what works for you.

I hope these help, I am sure there are plenty of other ways to do this, these are some I have used.

Regards,

Neil

Comment: thanks my good friend. please read chris answer it is very nice.

Comment: @sajadkhammar i am aware of using layer modes but it is dependent on removing part of another layer and can change the colours