# What is the best way to heal out hair from shoulder using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have to tidy up the hair from this (cropped) image. I used the spot healing, Healing Brush and the Patch tool, however, each one presents an issue. The contrast of the hair on the black is creating a hazing or blurring as you can see from the image below.

What can I do to make the healing better?

[image]

Original Image
[image]

Comment: Spot heal works up to a point - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CawH1.png - It can't make any headway over the bits you already did, though; they're already beyond repair. Post the same crop pre-healing.

Comment: take a look at this question about hair selection, it might help you with 90% of your problem https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/techniques-for-cutting-out-hair-accurately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try making a *patch*

- Use the **Stamp Tool** to recover a clean part of the shoulder, making different reference points

[image: shoulder]

- Make a selection around this clean area and create a **Layer Via Copying**

[image: selection]

- Move this layer where the hair is and duplicate it until cover all the shoulder area

[image: duplicates]

- Merge all the duplicate layers and set the opacity to 50%.
- Use the **Eraser Tool** to delete the surplus area outside the shoulder and define the hair border

[image: opacity]

- Set the opacity to 100% and use the **Stamp Tool** to fix
- Click the Lock Transparent Icon and apply a Median filter to remove marks
- Add a Noise filter

[image: median]

Sometimes retouching an image is not just using a simple tool

[image: END]