# How to isolate a cat's whiskers from background in Photoshop 2020?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, background-removal

This is our cat:

[image]

I am attempting to isolate her whiskers from the background:

[image]

The Object Selection Tool does an excellent job of identifying the cat and selecting it but it struggles with the whiskers.

What would be the most effective method to include the whiskers in the mask selection?

Any advice on the best way to approach this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Photoshop CC's Select and Mask functionality would be good for this.  You can create [an almost perfect mask](https://imgur.com/a/4L3vd9C) with the tools provided.  A tutorial here would be too long, perhaps have a look at tutorial vids on youtube.

Comment: I mentioned Select and Mask in my question actually. Which settings did you use to get the whiskers to show up so nicely?

Comment: It's not so much about settings but how you use the tools. Make a manual selection using the Quick Select tool making sure to include all the whiskers, then refine the mask by painting over the whiskers and the fluffy furry areas with the Refine Edge Brush Tool. Decontaminate Colours will bring back some darkness to the whiskers.  Make adjustments with the Shift Edge slider. Zoom in and you can remove any left over parts of the background between the whiskers using the Quick Select tool set to a very small size. Use the Black and White view frequently to check the mask as you work.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the Refine Edge Brush tool to be useful for this for some reason. When I use it, it seems to remove part of the whiskers themselves if I also paint over them. Should I be painting *around* the whiskers with the REB tool and not actually painting over them? I've already watched many tutorials but they mostly seem to deal with hair/fur, rather than whiskers (which seem a bit harder to do.)

Comment: You don't have to go around the individual whiskers with the REB tool.  Centre the tool on part of the background near the whiskers, then paint over all the whiskers and background to be removed, just paint over everything all in one go.  I'd love to create a video tutorial for you but GDSE isn't the place for that.

Comment: It's not for cat whiskers - but [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0QDp6umxy0) deals with the same issues.

Comment: Is this a good starting point for the initial selection of the whiskers? https://i.imgur.com/m0cTLQB.png Would you advise against starting with a detailed selection like this? https://i.imgur.com/VrPI0Ur.png How's this for an edge selection? https://i.imgur.com/HabjjCW.png I wonder what I'm doing wrong. https://i.imgur.com/jw0iyoY.png I'm struggling to remove the background area.

Comment: You don't need a detailed selection. That's the whole point of select and mask.  You could select them in one big blob, and work from there, or just select the cat without whiskers, and work from there. Scott Kelby doesn't even select the hairs at all in his tutorial.  Did you try following it?

Comment: I tried following it and I'm getting closer now I think: https://i.imgur.com/c3xuHPk.png. How can I avoid having problems in the area where the cat's whiskers meet her face (red arrow). Also, what's the best way to tidy up the messy smudges (green arrow) introduced by enabling Decontaminate Colors? You mentioned the Quick Selection Tool but it does strange things when I try to use it to remove smudges, like delete *way* more than I want it to - and there seems to be no way to control how aggressively it behaves! Sometimes it removes parts of the whiskers when I'm not even that close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103453/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-mr-ethernet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Techniques for cutting out hair accurately](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/techniques-for-cutting-out-hair-accurately)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create the following image using Billy Kerr's brilliant advice:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

make black and white
[image: make black and white]

increase contrast

[image: increase contrast]

cleanup and use as mask

[image: cleanup and use as mask]

The trick is to photograph against a very light background then this is easiest to mask.

Answer (score 2):

Single hairs and whiskers are often badly mixed with the background because they are so narrow. A great part of the width has pixels which are a mixture of the background and the right hair or whisker color. Low resolution and JPG compression artefacts make the situation even more difficult.

Pro photographers use very high resolution and they especially prepare the light and background so that the masking of hairs and whiskers is possible.

Your image is a lucky case and you have already got a method which can save a substantial part of the whiskers. If there were more complex or darker background the masking by increasing the contrast would have been less successful.

[image]

**Your original idea** (which has been lately removed from the question) to draw the lost whiskers with the pen was just about to be a success. The only missing thing was the lack of flexible enough brush, but that exists in Illustrator. You can make an art brush. Draw a narrow long grey horizontal triangle, drag it to the brushes collection and draw with it the needed curves. Use the pen tool and apply the brush after the curves are right. Use your original photo as a reference (lock it!)

[image]

Copy the drawn whiskers to the clipboard and paste them in Photoshop as a new pixel layer to a image where the background and the whiskers along it has been erased. Adjust the brightness, contrast and layer transparency for good appearance.

Unfortunately single grey isn't the best possible color for the whiskers. Acceptable result needs more complexity. Here's one adjustment version:

[image]

There's a colored test background for proper adjustments. The whisker and it's color adjustment layers are grouped to a layer group which has reduced opacity like the real whiskers in a normal photo do have.

There's 2 curves adjustment layers. The lower curves layer changes the base grey to something which fits the fur (=quite dark). The upper curves layer has a layer mask which makes the whiskers only somehow brighter in the middle to simulate how they shine

This is the color which is matched with the fur:

[image]

And this is the effect of the upper curves layer:

[image]

A high zoom view shows that the whiskers are as badly mixed with the background as in your original image, but so it should be to look plausible. The difference is that now you have the control:

[image]

**NOT ASKED:** The edge of the cat was too clean when a simple BG removal with the quick selection tool was applied. That happens often when one tries to be fast. The edge is re-roughened with the smudge tool. The used brush was one of the default multiparticle brushes.